# Source of cartoon lampooning Felix Klein

Tags: physics, mathematicians

There is an interesting cartoon in the book

> Lillian Hoddeson, Ernst Braun, Jurgen Teichmann, Spencer Weart (Eds.) Out of the Crystal Maze: Chapters from The History of Solid State Physics. Oxford Univesity Press, 1992 (online [here](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=WCpPPHhMdRcC&printsec=frontcover&vq=cartoon&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=cartoon&f=false))

The cartoon (see below) appears on page 15 and depicts recognizably professorial types exchanging books for cartoonish bags of coins brought by recognizably capitalist types. Hovering over the scene are a sun-like Felix Klein and an angelic-looking [Friedrich Althoff](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Althoff), depicted as bestowing blessings upon the congregants. The book says that the cartoon dates from 1908 but does not provide any additional details.

***Question 1.*** Where did the cartoon first appear in 1908?

***Question 2.*** Who created the cartoon?

***Question 3.*** Althoff died on 20 october 1908.  Did the cartoon appear before or after his death in 1908?

***Question 4.*** There are several books that have reprinted this cartoon and they all seem to agree that the cartoon originates from 1908.  Where did they get this information from?

***Question 5.*** Armin Hermann writes in his 1991 book that the cartoon was distributed with the invitations to a february 1908 meeting at Goettingen, as pointed out in [this answer](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/7023/604).  Where does Hermann's information come from?

[image]

Comment: I clicked on that link to the book. The caption on the image says: "From A. Hermann, *Weltreich der Physik* [Esslingen: Bechtle, 1980], 193)". Perhaps that reference has more detail about the original 1908 source? I will also edit your post to include the image, so others do not need to click the link.

Comment: Thanks, Brendan.  Indeed I am interested in its original appearance in 1908.

Comment: There is quite a fun caricature of Alhoff , "the Academic Owl", on the page numbered 793 (PDF page 13) of http://www.academia.edu/31882285/Baltimore_Teaches_G%C3%B6ttingen_Learns_Cooperation_Competition_and_the_Research_University_The_American_Historical_Review_June_2016_780_823

Comment: @NickR, are you referring to the "Baltimore teachers" piece?  They wouldn't let me get the pdf without registering.  Would you be so kind as to send me a pdf?

Comment: I wonder whether Google's image-matching search engine would be of any help.

Comment: @MikhailKatz That's odd.  I'm not a member and I am able to view the PDF.  I shall email you a copy at the address indicated on your profile "math.biu.ac.il where x=katzmik ".

Comment: Thanks, got it.  Perhaps if you are located in the same geographic area the access is less tightly controlled. MK

Comment: @BrendanW.Sullivan would you happen to have a pdf of Hermann's 1980 book?

Comment: @MikhailKatz Alas, I do not. I will see if my university library has a copy.

Comment: That's interesting.  How did you get the image if you don't have the book? @BrendanW.Sullivan

Comment: @MikhailKatz It appears in the link in your post! Page 15: https://books.google.co.il/books?id=WCpPPHhMdRcC&printsec=frontcover&vq=cartoon&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=cartoon&f=false

Comment: Oh, OK.  I thought you got it from page 193 in Hermann.

Answer (score 8):

Armin Hermann states in his book on [page 355](https://books.google.de/books?id=vrrPBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA355&lpg=PA355) that this caricature was enclosed in the invitation letters. Since the anniversary meeting was held in February 1908, it appeared before Althoff's death. Here the conference proceedings can be downloaded: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-663-15735-9

Comment: Is there any way of finding out where Armin Hermann got his information from?